# How can closures access destructed variables?

Tags: javascript, oop, closures

while I was learning ways to create Objects I found **Durable Constructor Pattern** which depends on closures and the way to create private variables.

so for example:

```
function Person(name, age, job){
    var o = new Object();

    o.sayName = function(){
    alert(name);
    };

    return o;
}
var m = new Person('joe',20, 'anything');
m.sayName(); // 'joe'
```

`name` is private variable that can only accessed by `m.sayName`.

also I know that when the function finishes executing The garbage collector does a memory sweep so all local variables get freed.

so my question is that how `m.sayName` can access `name` while its memory has been freed after the constructor finished executing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the garbage collector only cleans the variables that aren't referenced.

The closure adds a reference from the `sayName` function to the execution context of `Person`, which is the scope referencing `name`.

This reference stays alive as long as `sayName` is referenced. The variable won't be garbaged until you free `m` (or directly `m.sayName`).

A closure must be seen as a reference from a function to the scope in which it was created (which is also why closures are often pointed as one of the common causes of memory leaks in JavaScript). This reference makes it possible for the variables of the creation scope to be accessed from the inner function (they're not copies, which means two inner functions share the same variables).

The reference to the closure scope is hidden from your code but you can see it with developer tools. Here's what I see if I do `console.dir(m)` in Chrome :

[image]

Comment: That means that `sayName` has a reference to `name`?

Comment: @OmarElawady yes, indirectly. It has a hidden reference to the scope containing `name`.

Comment: so just appending a name of variable in a function creates a reference to it ?

Comment: Yes. But as soon as you dereference the function the variable is freed too.